# how to find clicked element on html?

Tags: jquery

i have some dive and each dive has its id like bellow.
i want when user click on my HTML at first find clicked elements is div and after than want to get id and inner HTML of selected div .

i do not want to use methods like onclick() and.. on my div elements, is this way possible by jquery or somethings?

```
<div id="a2">123</div>
<div id="a1">456</div>
```

i used this code but not works

```
$('html').click(function () {
    var selectedelement = jQuery('div');
});
```

Comment: Why are you attaching the handler to the html element when what you want is to capture clicks on the divs? have you tryed using delegation? maybe attach the handlers to the actual divs if they are not dynamically generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('div').click(function () {
    var selectedelement = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(selectedelement);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.someClassForYourDivs').click(function () {
    var selectedelement = $(this);
});
```

The value of `this` in jQuery is typically set to whatever object the event was fired on.  Also, as cernunnos pointed out, you should add this click handler to the specific elements you want.  Assign a class to them to make this easy.

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is adding a click event to the 'HTML' node.  You want to do the f9ollowing if all you care about are div's which I would recommend because the selector will get any DIV:

```
$('div').click(function () {
    var selectedelement = this;
});
```

If you only care about the DIV with ID's 'a1' anbd 'a2', do the following:

```
$('#a1,#a2').click(function () {
        var selectedelement = this;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use delegation, which works well if you are dynamically adding the divs to the page:

```
$("html").on("click", "div", function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DGeF9/